# You may destroy target base - can this destroy outposts before combat damage is done?

Tags: star-realms

Some cards have an ability - 'you may destroy target base'. The rules say that a ships primary ability is triggered immediately when it is played. If I use a ship with that ability and combat points, can I destroy an opponent's outpost using this ability, before using my combat points to damage my opponent's authority or another base, or are the combat points immediately used on the outpost?

My understanding is that both the combat points and the text ability are used effectively simultaneously, so I can choose to do either first.

If that is correct, what about the case of the Blob Destroyer, where the base-destroying ability is only activated when the second Blob ship/base is out? Do I have to play the Blob Destroyer after another blob to take advantage of this ability on the outpost, leaving myself in the situation of deciding which Blob's combat points to waste on the outpost before it is destroyed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can destroy the base first.  There is no requirement that combat points be used immediately.

From the Two Player rules link at http://www.starrealms.com/learn-to-play/

If an ability grants Combat or trade, that resource goes into a resource pool, which can be used at any point during the Main Phase.

Note that the electronic version of the game acts the same way.